# Angular JS Factory -- undefined is not an object issue

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. 
Here is my issue.
I am trying to create a factory .
But when I am calling factory it gives me an error 
-Error undefined is not an object (evaluating: myService.getProjects)

Code:

```
myApp.factory('myService', function() { 
  return {
    getProjects: function() {
        return "Test";
    }
  };
});

myApp.controller('homeController',['$scope',function($scope,myService)
{
 $scope.projects=myService.getProjects();
 $scope.message="homeController";
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to inject your service. Try this:

```
myApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.projects = myService.getProjects();
  $scope.message = "homeController";
}]);
```

Comment: Nice answer @Florian, This was getting the better of me. I keep forgetting to inject the service now that I am using the brackets to preserve code for minification.